# Eventloop group constructor when using fixed channel pool

Tags: netty

I have client implementation of a fixed pool with 10 connections. The NIOEventloop group is instantiated with the no-arg constructor. I have observed that this infact is creating 8 threads ( the default that kicks in ). Now, i can see in my logs that each of my 10 channels are reusing threads. two threads seems to be serving two channels each and the other 6 channels seem to have their own dedicated thread. Now, if i use the eventloop group constructor with 10 threads, will it guarantee that each channel gets its own thread? I am thiking a dedicated thread is good but not sure about that either. Please let me know what the best practice is

Answer (score 0):

With the default implementation yes (but this is really an impl detail). That said this defeats a bit of the point of non-blocking IO where you usually handle multiple connections per EventLoop and so per Thread. As long as you dont block in the EventLoop thread you should easily be able to handle thousands of connections with one thread.

Comment: Thanks Norman, when you say you can handle many connection as long as you don’t block, you are hinting that we off load to a processing thread correct ? . That again could be a threadpool, executor service or the likes.  Now if I have as many threads as the channels, I can technically block in my thread without starving any other channels ?